# XML documentation comments with Database First Models in ASP.NET and EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, comments, ef-database-first

I would like to add [XML documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/) to our models.

Normally, one would just add a comment block with a summary above the model class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic summary of the model.
/// </summary>
public class MyModel {}
```

The thing is that we use Database First approach so that our models are generated from Database, and therefore, all model files are overwritten each time the models are updated.

The models are partial classes, so would it be wise to just create duplicate empty partial classes in separate files and add the comment block to each of them? It works but I think it's just too messy. What is the best option?

**MyModel.commented.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic summary of the model.
/// </summary>
public partial class MyModel {}
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
// autogenerated
public partial class MyModel 
{
    ...
}
```

Another thing is how to add comments inside the class to its data fields?

Comment: You have to store it somewhere, and if you generate the source code, why not also generating the comments. You store a table "MyModel;BasisSummary of the model" somewhere, scan all your generated files for "class MyModel" and put the comment above it,after generation.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we should create more tables, generate models and then copy-paste the comments each time the models are refreshed?

Comment: You should do the Copy&Paste programmaticly.(insert strings in a text-file) It's easy to search for the right position.  So after model creation you press one more button or maybe it's an automated post-build step of the code-generation. Just an idea. But you definitly have to store your comments on a persistent place as first step. And everytime you modify your SQL-Structure, you have to maintain your table of comments also. Building the C# model means to bring the SQL-structure and the comments together into one set of files.

Comment: With your partial class idea, you cannot put comments on DbSets, fields and properties. For Entity classes only, it might be nice.

Comment: Just read something about `public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)` you can modify this in the T4-generator that creates your source-file. That's the function generating the class headers. Haven't tried but maybe google helps for details.